# Write Numpy operations using Tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have this numpy code I wish to use inside my loss function:

```
import numpy as np

y_true = np.random.randint(10, size=10000)
y_pred = np.random.randint(10, size=10000)
A = np.random.randint(12, size=(12,12))

S = -np.sum(A[y_true[:], y_pred[:]])
```

Obs: The "A" is 2-dimensional numpy array, the "penalty matrix" I need to use for my loss function and its dimensions are 12x12. Both y_true and y_pred are nx1 numpy arrays
It works fine, but what I actually want is the Tensor version of it. I have tried the following already:

```
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.constant(A)
y_true = tf.constant(y_true)
y_pred = tf.constant(y_pred)

S = -K.sum(A[y_true[:], y_pred[:]])
```

Obs: The "A" in this case is a 2-dimensional tensor, the "penalty matrix" I need to use for my loss function and its dimensions are 12x12. Both y_true and y_pred are Nx1 tensors.
I want to performs the same operation but using Tensors. I have tried the following already:
But I got the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [2,12,1], [2,12,1], and [2] instead. [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. Something that users can copy and paste and run without having to change anything.

Comment: Ok, added some sample data just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) for this.

```
tf.gather_nd(A, tf.stack((y_true, y_pred), axis=-1))
```

is equivalent to

```
A[y_true, y_pred]
```

Please see below for complete numpy and tensorflow code.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

K = tf.keras.backend

y_true = np.random.randint(10, size=10000)
y_pred = np.random.randint(10, size=10000)
A = np.random.randint(12, size=(12,12))

S_np = -np.sum(A[y_true, y_pred])
S_tf = -K.sum(tf.gather_nd(A, tf.stack((y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)))

assert S_np == S_tf.numpy()
```

By the way, `y_true[:]` is redundant in this case and can be written as `y_true`.

Also, do not mix `tf.keras` and `keras`. I am not sure if you were, but please stick to one or the other, preferably `tf.keras`.